# Making HashMap Iterators fail "faster"

Tags: java, collections

While going though Open Java 1.8's fail fast behavior I noticed that in the `put(k,v)` we don't raise the `modCount` when there is an existing key whose value is replaced in the map. This is ok for the `keySet` collection iterators of HashMap but not optimal for `entrySet` view, since we could do better throw a CME for the latter if the underlying map is modified.

Wouldn't it make the fail-fast behavior "better" if there was a separate volatile flag like `modCount` for `entrySet` and `values` view that was raised in other places like I pointed out? Or am I missing something.

Comment: As far as I know, `modCount` is for structural changes only. Changing the value of an existing entry is not a structural modification, so I think it is OK as it is

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thanks, found: `A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings or, in the case of access-ordered linked hash maps, affects iteration order. In insertion-ordered linked hash maps, merely changing the value associated with a key that is already contained in the map is not a structural modification. In access-ordered linked hash maps, merely querying the map with get is a structural modification. ` like you said